# How many bytes is a kilobyte in `ps` command?

Tags: ps

I use `ps` command to get information about the memory consumption of a process. According to the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), the memory size unit is "kilobyte". Is that 1024 bytes or 1000 bytes? Can you provide a reference to a documentation addresses it?

Answer (score 2):

I’m not aware of *documentation* which explicitly states this; but on Linux, [`ps` reads the RSS value from `/proc/.../status`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/d79157db5122c4d09a46834d53ec503d344c792e/proc/readproc.c#L340), and [that is a shifted page count](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.10/source/fs/proc/task_mmu.c#L28), so counted in kibibytes (1024 byte units).